# How can I do a simple AJAX call to play audio via React / Redux?

Tags: ajax, reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to auto play some audio, and on iOS, it won't autoplay. However, if I wrap it in an AJAX call, it'll fire. So here's what I have:

```
// run on page load
var audio = document.getElementById('audio');

jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'ajax.js',
    async: false,
    success: function() {
        audio.play(); // audio will play in iOS before 4.2.1
    }
});
```

How would I set this up with React / Redux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a very simple example using [fetch](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/) (which is supported by most browsers out of the box) and `blob` object URLs. You could of course also use jQuery's `ajax`.

It's very similar to your code, but inside the `componentDidMount` method. The `audio` element is referenced via [React's `refs`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

```js
class Player extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(this.props.src)
      .then(res => res.blob())
      .then(blob => {
        const { audio } = this.refs;
        audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        audio.play();
      });
  }
  render() {
    return <audio ref="audio" controls></audio>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Player src="https://ia802508.us.archive.org/5/items/testmp3testfile/mpthreetest.mp3" />,
  document.getElementById("View")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id='View'></div>
```

❗️

Also, it is usually not recommended to use `refs` in React, but since we need access to the actual DOM node of the audio player it is a necessary evil.